# Laravel/nexmo conflict with elasticsearch/elasticsearch your requirements or minimum-stability

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, vonage

I am trying to install nexmo/laravel on my project I am getting this error
`The requested package elasticsearch/elasticsearch (locked at v7.3.0, required as 7.0.2) is satisfiable by elasticsearch/elasticsearch[v7.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.`

I can't downgrade elasticsearch because it will create issue in the project.How i can fix this issue and install this package.

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually a problem with the Nexmo packages, `nexmo/laravel` nor `laravel/nexmo-notification-channel` themselves depend on any elasticsearch components. What exact command are you using to install the new packages (especially as there is no package named `laravel/nexmo` itself)?

Comment: @dragonmantank I am using this command to install  COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require nexmo/laravel .Also here is the link to https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-laravel where I am getting the package.

Comment: Can you update the question with the full output from the failure? `nexmo/laravel` does not depend on anything but `illuminate/support` and the `nexmo/client` library, and the base Nexmo/Vonage packages do not require elasticsearch in any way. The full error will help determine where the problem is cropping up. My gut feeling is some other Laravel package is attempting to update as well.

Comment: Using version ^2.4 for nexmo/laravel
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package elasticsearch/elasticsearch (locked at v7.3.0, required as 7.0.2) is satisfiable by elasticsearch/elasticsearch[v7.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: I am getting just this error  Problem 1 - The requested package elasticsearch/elasticsearch (locked at v7.3.0, required as 7.0.2) is satisfiable by elasticsearch/elasticsearch[v7.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability

Comment: Actually my project is using elastic search i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`locked at v7.3.0, required as 7.0.2` sounds as if your `composer.lock` and `composer.json` files are out of sync. Try deleting `composer.lock` and your `vendor/` directory (if it exists), and do `composer install`.

If that works, update your `composer.json` to require the correct version of Elasticsearch you need. `composer update elasticsearch/elasticsearch:^7.3` should probably work to do that.

Comment: I have tried but getting an other error Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
  [ErrorException]
  include(/home/vagrant/steamatic-backend/vendor/composer/package-versions-deprecated/src/PackageVersions/Installer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages]

Comment: Best thing to do for this is probably delete your `vendor/` directory and the `composer.lock` files, and re-run `composer update`. It looks like a file is missing from the vendor directory and this is the easiest way to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue with by matching composer.json and composer.lock elasticsearch version.I have change 7.3.0 in composer.lock to 7.0.2 and try to install nexmo package and it installed successfully.